# Definite integral of $f:[0,a]\to \mathbb{R} \quad f(x)=x^2$ using Darboux sums?

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-sum

I seem to be completely lost with integration.

> I have to integrate  $f(x)=x^2$ on $x\in[0,a]$

What I have got so far:
I partition the interval $[0,a]$
$$ 0 = x_0 < x_1 < \dots < x_{n-1} < x_n = a $$
So the subintervals are
$ [x_{i}-x_{i-1}] $ long.
I know that in Darboux integration, it is not necessary for the rectangles (the ones which approximate the function from below and above) to have equal width. Their height is either $$m_i = \inf_{x \in [x_{i-1},x_i]}f(x),$$ for the rectangles below or $$M_i=\sup_{x \in [x_{i-1},x_i]}f(x),$$ that is for the rectangles 'above'. So the lower Darboux sum is:
$$ L(f,P)=\sum_{i}^{n}{m_i(x_{i}-x_{i-1})} $$
and the other one is:
$$ U(f,P)=\sum_{i}^{n}{M_i(x_{i}-x_{i-1})}$$
I can see, from the graph of the function, that $m_i=x_{i-1}^2$ and $M_i=x_i^2$ so I can plug those in:
$$ L(f,P)=\sum_{i}^{n}{x_{i-1}^2(x_{i}-x_{i-1})} $$
I could do the same with the upper one. But here I am stuck, don't I need to somehow define an $x_i$? A partition? But how do I do that without making all the subintervals of equal length? Integrating on $[0,1]$ is easier, because I can say that they are of equal length and it is $\frac{1}{n}$, so $n$ number of these equals $1$ and that is the 'right side' of the interval.

I think I am am missing something here.
Could you please elaborate so that I can understand what this is all about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any polynomial is a continuous function: in particular, any polynomial is Riemann-integrable over a compact interval. Once we have Riemann integrability granted, we may just consider uniform partitions of the integration range, leading to
$$ \int_{0}^{a}x^2\,dx =\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{ak}{n}\right)^2 =a^3 \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2.\tag{1}$$
Due to the [Hockey-stick identity](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Combinatorial_identity) we have
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{k}{2}=\binom{n+1}{3},\qquad \sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{k}{1}=\binom{n+1}{2}\tag{2}$$
hence from $k^2 = 2\binom{k}{2}+\binom{k}{1}$ it follows that
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} \tag{3}$$
and by plugging in such identity into the RHS of $(1)$ we get:

$$ \int_{0}^{a}x^2\,dx = a^3 \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n^3}=\color{red}{\frac{a^3}{3}}.\tag{4}$$

Comment: Isn't what you are doing here basically defining each subinterval to be $\frac{a}{n}$ long? And $x_i=\frac{ai}{n}$? So the height of a rectangle is $m_i=\frac{a(i-1)}{n}$? (I prefer to use $i$ instead of $k$)

Comment: @bertalanp99: exactly. We are allowed to consider just uniform partitions since Riemann integrability is a straightforward consequence of continuity, and continuity is trivial. For any partition with maximum gap $\delta$, there is a uniform partition with maximum gap $\leq\delta$: so, since we know in advance that the integral, as the limit on the whole set of partitions, exists, we may compute it by just considering the limit along the set of uniform partitions.